# How to get a callback when a Text element is pressed down and have the callback include information about which character was pressed?

Tags: android-jetpack-compose, android-compose-textfield

I have a [Text](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/material/package-summary#Text(kotlin.String,androidx.compose.ui.Modifier,androidx.compose.ui.graphics.Color,androidx.compose.ui.unit.TextUnit,androidx.compose.ui.text.font.FontStyle,androidx.compose.ui.text.font.FontWeight,androidx.compose.ui.text.font.FontFamily,androidx.compose.ui.unit.TextUnit,androidx.compose.ui.text.style.TextDecoration,androidx.compose.ui.text.style.TextAlign,androidx.compose.ui.unit.TextUnit,androidx.compose.ui.text.style.TextOverflow,kotlin.Boolean,kotlin.Int,kotlin.Int,kotlin.Function1,androidx.compose.ui.text.TextStyle)) element that contains a number of links.

I want to know when the [Text](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/material/package-summary#Text(kotlin.String,androidx.compose.ui.Modifier,androidx.compose.ui.graphics.Color,androidx.compose.ui.unit.TextUnit,androidx.compose.ui.text.font.FontStyle,androidx.compose.ui.text.font.FontWeight,androidx.compose.ui.text.font.FontFamily,androidx.compose.ui.unit.TextUnit,androidx.compose.ui.text.style.TextDecoration,androidx.compose.ui.text.style.TextAlign,androidx.compose.ui.unit.TextUnit,androidx.compose.ui.text.style.TextOverflow,kotlin.Boolean,kotlin.Int,kotlin.Int,kotlin.Function1,androidx.compose.ui.text.TextStyle)) element is pressed down and I want to know which character within the [Text](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/material/package-summary#Text(kotlin.String,androidx.compose.ui.Modifier,androidx.compose.ui.graphics.Color,androidx.compose.ui.unit.TextUnit,androidx.compose.ui.text.font.FontStyle,androidx.compose.ui.text.font.FontWeight,androidx.compose.ui.text.font.FontFamily,androidx.compose.ui.unit.TextUnit,androidx.compose.ui.text.style.TextDecoration,androidx.compose.ui.text.style.TextAlign,androidx.compose.ui.unit.TextUnit,androidx.compose.ui.text.style.TextOverflow,kotlin.Boolean,kotlin.Int,kotlin.Int,kotlin.Function1,androidx.compose.ui.text.TextStyle)) element was pressed down so that I can change the appearance of the appropriate link.

Is this possible? If so, how?

### Addendum

The [ClickableText](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/foundation/text/package-summary#ClickableText(androidx.compose.ui.text.AnnotatedString,kotlin.Function1,androidx.compose.ui.Modifier,androidx.compose.ui.text.TextStyle,kotlin.Boolean,androidx.compose.ui.text.style.TextOverflow,kotlin.Int,kotlin.Function1,kotlin.Function1)) element does offer `onClick` and `onHover` callbacks but neither of these trigger when the element is pressed down. The `onClick` callback is called when the press is released. The `onHover` callback is called when the press moves from one character in the text to another.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a helpful code block at the end of the [ClickableText](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/foundation/text/package-summary#ClickableText(androidx.compose.ui.text.AnnotatedString,kotlin.Function1,androidx.compose.ui.Modifier,androidx.compose.ui.text.TextStyle,kotlin.Boolean,androidx.compose.ui.text.style.TextOverflow,kotlin.Int,kotlin.Function1,kotlin.Function1)) documentation that demonstrates how to configure a [Text](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/material/package-summary#Text(kotlin.String,androidx.compose.ui.Modifier,androidx.compose.ui.graphics.Color,androidx.compose.ui.unit.TextUnit,androidx.compose.ui.text.font.FontStyle,androidx.compose.ui.text.font.FontWeight,androidx.compose.ui.text.font.FontFamily,androidx.compose.ui.unit.TextUnit,androidx.compose.ui.text.style.TextDecoration,androidx.compose.ui.text.style.TextAlign,androidx.compose.ui.unit.TextUnit,androidx.compose.ui.text.style.TextOverflow,kotlin.Boolean,kotlin.Int,kotlin.Int,kotlin.Function1,androidx.compose.ui.text.TextStyle)) element to detect "long press" gestures. You can tweak this code block to detect "pressed down" and "press released" events instead of "long press" gestures.

Here's one way to achieve this:

```kotlin
var pressedCharacterPosition by remember { mutableStateOf<Int?>(null) }

var layoutResult by remember { mutableStateOf<TextLayoutResult?>(null) }

val pointerInputModifier = Modifier.pointerInput(Unit) {
    detectTapGestures(
        onPress = { offset ->
            val unwrappedLayoutResult = layoutResult ?: return@detectTapGestures

            pressedCharacterPosition = unwrappedLayoutResult.getOffsetForPosition(offset)

            Log.d("Foo", "onPress: pressedCharacterPosition = $pressedCharacterPosition")

            val pressWasReleased = tryAwaitRelease()

            Log.d("Foo", "onPress: pressWasReleased = $pressWasReleased")

            pressedCharacterPosition = null
        },
        onTap = { offset ->
            val unwrappedLayoutResult = layoutResult ?: return@detectTapGestures

            val characterPosition = unwrappedLayoutResult.getOffsetForPosition(offset)

            Log.d("Foo", "onTap: characterPosition = $characterPosition")

            // perform whatever action you need to here
        }
    )
}

Text(
    text = getText(pressedCharacterPosition),
    modifier = Modifier.then(pointerInputModifier),
    onTextLayout = { layoutResult = it }
)
```

The `getText(pressedCharacterPosition: Int?): AnnotatedString` function is up to you to define based on your particular needs.

For a concrete example of all this, see [app1](https://github.com/adil-hussain-84/jetpack-compose-experiments/tree/main/app1) in the [jetpack-compose-experiments](https://github.com/adil-hussain-84/jetpack-compose-experiments/tree/main) repository.